# Java vs. firewall: how to let Java applications have their own set of rules

Tags: java, firewall

Let's say I have coded a Java application that requires Internet access. Usually the firewall pops up and asks whether or not this is OK. Now I have the options to generally allow Internet access or use specific rules. Since I only check a web service I'd set a rule that restricts access to exactly that server at some port.

Now I have Java application #2 that also requires Internet access. If I decided to give application #1 full access then #2 also has full access. For the solution with the rule set above I'd need to add another rule or just give up and grant full access and, therefore, also give application #1 full access.

I guess you can see what my problem is. A while ago I ran into the same situation and I tried one or two wrappers that convert a JAR into an executable. I noticed that in the end they simply launched the JVM causing the usual Java binary to open the Internet connection.

So my question is: which options do I have to allow a user to specify different firewall rules for each Java application?

**EDIT**: after reading the first comment I'd like to make clear that I'm not thinking about how to configure the firewall, but rather have some way that Java applications themselves have a more or less unique way of identifying themselves or have another way of handling network access.

Comment: This a question on how to configure a specific, but unnamed personal firewall product for some specific, but unnamed OS. Should go to SuperUser.

Comment: @Luther No, I think you got it wrong. It's more a thing on how to make the Java application identify itself differently to the firewall. So I think it's more of a coding thing or how to deploy a Java application. The definition of the firewall rules should be like defining them for any other non-Java application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you require is more fine grained access. Why not author a policy file and allow the security manager to govern the `SocketPermissions` that are allotted to your program?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html.

Example below.

```
grant signedBy "paul" {
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:1024-", "accept, connect, listen";
};
```

Comment: how do I specify a package as a `codeBase`? The documentations only refer to local stuff via "file://" and some web-stuff.

Answer (score 2):

A firewall is like a semi-permeable membrane, allowing outbound but not inbound connections:

```
                      |
 Outside world <===== | ====== Your computer
                      |
                   Firewall [OK]


                      |
 Outside world ====== X =====> Your computer
                      |
                   Firewall [Disallowed]
```

One thing that you can do to get around this is to setup a proxy that is outside of the firewall that accepts inbound connections from the outside world, as well as inbound connections from your "real" server. The proxy can route the external requests to one of the inbound sockets from one of the servers:

```
                                   |
 Outside world ===> [Proxy] <===== | ====== Your computer
                                   |
                              Firewall [OK]
```

That said, without knowing your exact situation, this might not be the best design choice. For example, you might be doing something that does not really require running a server, or maybe you really do want to be running a server, but maybe should be running one on cloud computing infrastructure. It is hard to recommend an actual design without additional details as to what you wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Simple silly way around this. Copy and rename java.exe to different names.

If you have two apps rename java[w].exe to:

MyApp.exe

MyApp2.exe

then you can put specific rules in your firewall based on executable.

Comment: Oh no. What if install a new Java version? Then I'd have to copy that new binary to all executables. According to Murphy's Law I'll miss at least one ending up with plenty of different Java versions.

Comment: @sjngm You don't really want your app to change if they install a new version of Java. That means you'd have to support any new version of Java without having to run it through QA. By including a known tested version of the VM with your product you ensure you have a known system. With this idea in mind, it is not a problem to copy and rename the java.exe when a new version of Java is released. Any other wrapper will have the same problem when you upgrade java versions. Your alternative is to link explicitly to the jvm.dll and spawn your own VM instance inside native executables.

Comment: mklink firewall.app1.exe java.exe

Answer (score 0):

Ship your jvm with your product and write a script to launch it and set the necessary variables for it to function independent of any other jvm on the system.

I.e 
Classpath 
/app/launch/java -jar jar.file

This way only your version of java is launched.